# Proving order is well defined on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I am a sophomore in college and just started an introductory real analysis course. Our professor decided to start with the construction of real and rational numbers. I feel I have a good intuitive understanding of what this statement means, but cannot seem to reach conclusive results while creating a proof. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Given the relation $\sim$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ with (a,b) $\sim$ (c,d) when ad = bc.

Prove the following proposition

**Proposition.** Let (a,b), (c,d), (e,f), (g,h) $\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ with (a,b) $\sim$ (e,f) and (c,d) $\sim$ (g,h). If (a,b) < (c,d), then (e,f) < (g,h).

For clarification by (a,b) < (c,d) we can assume (cb - ad,db) > $\mathbb{O}$, where $\mathbb{O}$ is the additive inverse defined as (0,1). We can also assume that if (a,b) < (c,d), then (cb - ad)(db) > 0.

Here is what I know and where I am struggling:

I know that since (a,b) $\sim$ (e,f) that af = be and since (c,d) $\sim$ (g,h) that ch = dg. I also know since (a,b) < (c,d) that (cb - ad)(bd) > 0. To show that (e,f) < (g,h) I must show that (gf - eh)(hf) > 0. Initially I though to multiply af = be and ch = dg and subtract the equations to get (cb - ad)(bd) = (gf - eh)(hf), but after half an hour I wanted to try something else. A friend suggested showing that (cb - ad, db) $\sim$ (gf - eh)(hf), but neither of us could find a way. I have a strong feeling the latter is correct but need some guidance.

Comment: Under the relation it would mean a/b<c/d but our professor said we must pretend we do not know how fractions work.

Comment: Then how did he define $<$?

Comment: Yeah, you need to define $<$

Comment: Here is the definition he gave: we know (a,b) < (c,d) when A < (c,d) + (-a,b) = (cb - ad, db), where A is the additive identity defined as (0,1). He also went on to say that A < (cb-ad, db) when (cb-ad)(db) > 0. I hope that helps

Comment: Now, [present *your* attempt(s)](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to solve this exercise, and where you are stuck.

Comment: I know that since (a,b) $\sim$ (e,f) that af = be and since (c,d) $\sim$ (g,h) that ch = dg. I also know since (a,b) < (c,d) that (cb - ad)(bd) > 0. To show that (e,f) < (g,h) I must show that (gf - eh)(hf) > 0. Initially I though to multiply af = be and ch = dg and subtract the equations to get (cb - ad)(bd) = (gf - eh)(hf), but after half an hour I wanted to try something else. A friend suggested showing that (cb - ad, db) $\sim$ (gf - eh)(hf), but neither of us could find a way. I have a strong feeling the latter is correct but need some guidance.

Comment: Please edit that attempt into your question (rather than burying it in a comment), along with the definition you're using, and you'll be up and running.  General rule:  If you need to clarify an issue with your question, the appropriate act is usually an edit, not a comment.

Comment: Sorry I have never posted on here.

Comment: Hence the guidance.

Comment: So you're defining $(a,b)<(c,d)$ to mean that $(c,d)-(a,b)$ is positive. I would break this into two parts: Prove that subtraction is well-defined, and then prove that [positivity is well-defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520695/472818).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f,g\in\Bbb Z$ with $b,d,f,h\ne0.$ If
$$af=be\quad\text{and}\quad ch=dg,$$
then
$$(gf-eh)bd=dgfb-behd=chfb-afhd=(cb-ad)hf
$$
hence if moreover
$$(cb-ad)bd>0,$$
then
$$(gf-eh)hf(bd)^2=(cb-ad)bd(hf)^2>0$$
which implies
$$(gf-eh)hf>0.$$